# Add-on not Visible in Marketplace

Tags: google-oauth, google-docs, add-on, google-apps-marketplace, google-developers-console

Google Cloud Platform's Tech Support directed me here.

GCP is telling me the add-on is "successfully verified and add-on is available for users." The OAuth Consent Screen confirms this.

In Developer Dashboard, the add-on is published.  The "Publish in Marketplace" checkbox was checked upon submission for publication.

I've read through troves of online Google documentation, but still have not found the solution.

The docs add-on is OrangeSlice: Teacher Rubric.

ideas?  Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's here https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/orangeslice_teacher_rubric/852746965799. You can find the link in the G Suite Marketplace SDK.

Comment: Thank you. I was just yesterday when it was released!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, I think, Google is very busy.

There are three advertised approval steps but it took more to get the add-on listed.  It was approved first via Developer Dashboard crew.  After completing the GS Marketplace Configuration and then the GS Cloud for OAuth, it was approved twice more.  To the get add-on published, I needed to inform Developer Dashboard that it was approved by GS Cloud, THEN IT COULD BE RELEASED.

So if you're having issues, be persistent.  The Google team answers nicely but many questions go unanswered or are ambiguous.  There are many directions spread over several different pages: Marketplace, Cloud, Apps Scripts, OAuth App Verif FAQ, etc.  They mostly concur but there is plenty of vagueness and inconsistency which only added to my confusion.  I have 2 add-ons, one is a stripped down version of the other.  The stripped down version had more hoops to jump through for approval-verification and then release than the fully loaded version.  Not sure why.  Again, the Google team is nice but it feels like they are swamped and/or have an intra-system communication challenges.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example.. directions within an email from the Google team:

Please follow the steps below to ensure your OAuth scope(s) request is submitted for review:

1. Sign-in to the Google Cloud Console
2. Select the project-id: api-project-#############
3. Go to Credentials on the OAuth Consent Screen

.....Credentials and OAuth Consent screens are two separate screens under the same heading, API Apps & Services.  Neither exists within the other but next to each other.

So what to do?